# jQuery toggleClass to parent class when child has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the [Ratchet](http://maker.github.com/ratchet/) framework to prototype iPhone apps.

In Ratchet, they have [toggles](http://maker.github.com/ratchet/#toggles) that uses the class `toggle` and onclick (or tap), it uses `toggle` and `active`.

Using jQuery, how can I toggle a class to the parent parent element, so when the toggle has the class active, it adds a class (say `toggle-active`) to the parent parent element and when it doesn't have the class active, it removes have add that class. I've been looking at several different ways such as an if statement, onclick but I haven't found anything that works.

For example, this is what I tried:

jQuery

```
$(".toggle.active").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("toggle-active");
});
```

Markup

```
<div class="toggle"><div class="toggle-handle"></div></div>
```

Is `toggleClass` the problem or is it the function?

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing some HTML

Comment: The HTML is just `<div class="toggle"><div class="toggle-handle"></div></div>`

Comment: Great, now edit it into the question where people can see it.

Answer (score 2):

on click.. check it has class active with `hasClass` if yes add required class to parent.parent.. if no remove it...

try this

```
 $(".toggle").click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('active'){
     $(this).parent().parent().addClass("toggle-active");
     //or $(this).parents().eq(2).addClass("toggle-active"); //for find() or closest()

   }else{
     $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("toggle-active");
   }
});
```

Comment: Use `closest()` instead of `parent().parent()` imo

Comment: It's not working for me. Is it because of the click function? It could be a problem with Ratchet's toggles because you can't click on them on the desktop but you can tap on them on mobile.